# Ensuring safe and effective implementation of method swizzling

Tags: ios, swift

I'm exploring the concept of method swizzling in Swift and its potential use cases. While I understand that method swizzling can be a powerful tool to modify the behavior of methods at runtime, I'm also aware of the risks associated with it. I want to ensure that I approach this technique in a safe and effective manner.

I've read that method swizzling can lead to unexpected behavior in multi-threaded environments. What are the best practices to ensure thread safety when applying method swizzling? Are there any recommended synchronization mechanisms or patterns I should follow?

Comment: First and foremost, I'd avoid doing it altogether if possible. Otherwise, for the vast majority of use cases, I'd [`dispatch_once`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1447169-dispatch_once) it. If for some reason you need to un-swizzle or swizzle the same method multiple times, it'd probably be a good idea to wrap each case in a [`DispatchGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) or a [`DispatchSemaphore`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore). Whatever your usual favorite thread synchronization method is

Comment: Even with a locking mechanism like those tho, you can still almost never be totally safe. For example, any of your dependencies could also be swizzling the same stuff, which can lead to weird behavior, and it's always a debugging nightmare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, swizzling cannot be done in a safe manner. It is, by its nature, dangerous. It requires you to rely on internal implementation details of the modified class that are subject to change. I'm not saying that it should never be used (though in over 15 years of Cocoa development, I've never needed to write a swizzle for anything but debugging), but it must only be used with great care. You should only use it in proportion to how well you believe you know what Apple is doing internally and what they will possibly change in the future. If Apple changes something you didn't expect, the bugs can be extremely hard to understand.

And woe to the developer who discovers some other developer decided to swizzle the same thing. Never implicitly swizzle in libraries. (I'm looking at you, Firebase.) Multiple swizzles technically work and there's nothing inherently wrong about them, but they magnify how confusing things can get when something goes wrong. If you feel you must swizzle in a library, have the caller opt-in by calling some "setup" method, and clearly document what swizzles you're applying and their behavior.

The primary concern with threading and swizzling is that you might swizzle a class or object that already is doing things, and swizzling is not thread safe. You should strongly avoid doing that. Swizzle objects as soon as they come into existence, or as early in the program as possible. Class swizzling should ideally be done in [`+load`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418815-load#) method to make sure it happens before the class is used. If that's not possible, then `main()`. If that's not possible, then `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.

If you find yourself needing synchronization beyond `+load`, you are probably doing too much, or in too complicated a way, and you should try to simplify your implementation (ideally removing the swizzle entirely) rather than devising elaborate synchronization. If you still require that, you're on your own to devise an approach that works for your situation.

The most famous use of swizzling is [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002307-BAJEAIEE), and it introduces a lot of threading headaches. For a taste of how hard it is to solve the KVO threading problems, see [PMKVObserver](https://github.com/PMSwift/PMKVObserver). This would be the closest to an example of how to address your question as I know.

If you have something as dynamic as KVO, the best answer is generally to require the type to only be accessed on the main thread. If it's not one you control, that may be hard. That's part of why swizzling is a tricky tool.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I truly appreciate your emphasis on the cautious and careful use of method swizzling. It's clear that this technique carries inherent risks and complexities, and I'm taking this information to heart as I consider its application in my project.

Comment: Right, the optimal implementation for swizzling is to not use it entirely. I have it only used once, and I am pretty sure, there would have been a more resilient way to approach the problem. Now, I feel bad.